# How do you reference radiobuttons in views.py using Django or am I way off?

Tags: django, radio-button

I am trying to have a search feature for a database. The three different options or chemicals gases and supplies.

```
 <form action="/search/" method="get"> <input name="q" type="text"> 
 <input value="Search" type="submit"> 
 <input value="Chemicals" form="radiobuttons" name="item" type="radio">Chemicals&nbsp;      
 <input value="Gases" form="radiobuttons" name="item" type="radio">Gases&nbsp; 
 <input value="Supplies" form="radiobuttons" name="item" type="radio">Supplies </form>
```

this is the html that I am using. The search feature works like it should but I must be referencing the radio buttons wrong in my view which is posted below.

```
def search(request):
    error = False
    item = request.GET['item']
    if 'item' in request.GET and request.GET['item']:
        item = request.GET['item']
        if not item:
            error = True
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']
        if not q:
            error = True
        elif len(q) > 20:
            error = True
        else:
            if item == 'Chemicals':
                chemicals = Chemicals.objects.filter(Name__icontains=q)
                records = ChemicalRecord.objects.all()
                recordform = ChemicalRecordForm
            return render_to_response('search_results.html',locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return render_to_response('search_form.html',{'error':True})
```

Thanks, for any tips, advice, insights, or answers.

```
class RadioSelection(forms.Form):
CHOICES = (
    ('Chemicals','Chemicals'),
    ('Gasses','Gasses'),
    ('Supplies','Supplies'),
)
Button = forms.RadioSelect(choices=CHOICES)
```

and in the html I try and call it using {{form.Button}} which is what another user had posted on another question that was regarding radibuttons. Nothing show up and it validates correclty (so it says) so I'm not sure if the html is wrong or if the form is built incorrectly thanks.

Comment: why are you declaring it manually? You can just do `{{recordform|safe}}`

Comment: I can? Sorry I'm pretty new to django/python. This is all fairly new to me. So what exactly would that do?
Just found the radiobutton docs on the django website but any help or insights you share would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you saying that `request.GET['item']` is empty?

Comment: If I remove this line item = request.GET['item'] that occurs after error = False then when it checks the conditional for item == 'Chemicals' is says the variable is being referenced before being assigned. So I would say that it is not even getting anything from the radiobutton. Otherwise it would have at least created the variable and stuck something in it even if it was null. but I could be wrong.

Comment: @user2482595 - Check Al W's answer. That is what i was hinting at. Use django forms for validation, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) api.  It will make your life a lot simpler since it can include validation, data cleaning, reusable code, etc.

question was updated, here's more now that the code has changed.

you need to instantiate your form in your view method and then pass it to the template.  something like

```
def search(request)
   ...
   form = RadioSelection()
   ...

   render_to_response('search_results.html', {'form': form, ... }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

THEN in your template you can draw the whole form with just `{{form.as_p}}`

Incidentally, I'd avoid using locals() to pass parameters to your template... cleaner, sure, but it is not at all obvious as to what exactly is available to your template.

Comment: I think this is the way to go but am a little confused as to how I display the form on my page? I will edit what I have and perhaps someone can fill me in.

Answer (score 2):

While the forms framework is the way to go, your immediate problem is that none of your radio buttons have a `value` attribute.

Comment: Normally it would be done automatically if you were using a form defined in forms.py, but if you choose not to you would need to add it to the HTML.